# print a dictionary error: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python

I have dictionary like this:

```
team_dict = {
    'Iran': {
        'wins':ir_win,
        'loses':ir_lose,
        'draws':ir_draws,
        'goal difference':ir_goal,
        'points':ir_score
    },
    'Spain': {
        'wins':sp_win,
        'loses':sp_lose,
        'draws':sp_draws,
        'goal difference':sp_goal,
        'points':sp_score
    },
    'Portugal': {
        'wins':po_win,
        'loses':po_lose,
        'draws':po_draws,
        'goal difference':po_goal,
        'points':po_score
    },
    'Morocco': {
        'wins':ma_win,
        'loses':ma_lose,
        'draws':ma_draws,
        'goal difference':ma_goal,
        'points':ma_score
    }
}
```

Then I sorted it:

```
sorted_team_dict = sorted(
    team_dict.items(),
    key = lambda x: (-x[1].get('points'), -x[1].get('wins'), x[1].get('keys')
    )
)
```

I want to print the sorted one by:

```
for item in sorted_team_dict:
    print(
        "%s  wins:%i , loses:%i , draws:%i , goal difference:%i , points:%i" % (
            sorted_team_dict[item]["keys"],
            sorted_team_dict[item]["wins"],
            sorted_team_dict[item]["loses"],
            sorted_team_dict[item]["draws"],
            sorted_team_dict[item]["goal difference"],
            sorted_team_dict[item]["points"]
        )
    )
```

but I'm faced with the error below:

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

and I can't understand the meaning of error.

Comment: The error means that you are trying to access an item in a list, but instead of providing an integer (i.e. foo[1] ), you are providing a tuple (i.e. foo[(1,)] )

Comment: The short answer is you just need `item` not `sorted_team_dict[item]`, thats only half of your issues though. You should show what you've tried/researched to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `sorted_team_dict` is not a dictionary, but a list of tuples. So you would iterate through it like so:

```
for key, value in sorted_team_dict:
    print("%s  wins:%i , loses:%i , draws:%i , goal difference:%i , points:%i" %(key,value["wins"],value["loses"],value["draws"],value["goal difference"],value["points"]))
```

And you should probably rename it to `sorted_team_items` or something. The code could use other clean up as well, but that's outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Aslo, you could use f-string notation to format the string. e.g. f'My name is {name}'